# JS timestamp wrong - timezone setting

Tags: javascript, node.js, timestamp

When setting a date from a timestamp using JS, I obtain the wrong hour.

```
var timestamp = 1548374400000 //In milliseconds.
var time_string =  new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString("en-GB",{timezone:"Europe/London"})
console.log(time_string)
```

Which outputs:

```
25/01/2019, 01:00:00
```

However when checking on the following website: https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1548374400000&tz=Europe%2FLondon

I obtain that this timestamp (1548374400000) corresponds to the date:  Friday January 25, 2019 00:00:00 (am) in time zone Europe/London (GMT)

There is a one hour difference between these results that I cannot explain myself.

I have checked on this website to be sure this was an error on my side:
[image]

Comment: Refer to the docs on `toLocaleString()`

Comment: Voting to close as typo (`timeZone` is not `timezone`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var timestamp = 1548374400000; // In milliseconds.
var time_string = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString("en-GB", { timeZone: "Europe/London" });
console.log(time_string);
```

You just used the wrong keyword. Use code above should fix your problem.